# Why can't I access my req.body properties in Firebase functions while req.body does contain the properties?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get a property from the body from a firebase functions http request.
I am trying to get the lat and lng properties as follows:

```
exports.getAddressFromGeolocation = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const {lat, lng} = req.body;
}
```

If I log the lat and lng variables they are empty but if I log the req.body it shows this:

```
{
insertId: "*********"
jsonPayload: {
   data: {
      lat: 37.785834
      lng: -122.406417
}
```

Looking at the docs of firebase req.body.lat should bodyparse the property but it is not working and both req.body.lat and req.body.lng are undefined while req.body shows the properties in the jsonPayload.

I hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: `const {lat, lng} = req.body.data`

Comment: I thought I tried that but it seems like I didn't try it properly. It works! Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Konrad:

```
const {lat, lng} = req.body.data;
```

In your case you're not getting data due to incomplete syntax.

```
const {lat, lng} = req.body;
```